# In Process Explorer is it possible change scaling of activity graph the be able to further analyse graph?

Tags: freeze, process-explorer

Is there any way to zoom in, in the System Internals Process Explorer graph?

**Background**

I'm trying to work out why my PC freezes/locks up for about a second (the pointer does not move) every so often. This has only been happening for the last 2 days. There is a very narrow spike associated with the freeze, but it's hard to hover over it an analyse what is causing it.

My PC spec: ThinkPad X201S 1440x900 i7 2.0GHz 8Gb RAM, 256GB Samsung 840Pro SSD, Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit CalDigit USB 3.0 ExpressCard 34, Ultrabase X200 with DisplayPort to HDMI

[image: process explorer activity graph]

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that the freezing is the graphics hardware, though I don't know why this is suddenly happening: I've been using this machine since last October without issue. I am not using the trackpad - I am using a USB mouse. I have also notices that when music was playing when the freeze happened, this stuttered and went metallic sounding.

When I can actually hover over that steep peak, it reports that it is procexp64.exe - i.e. process explorer - now I know it's not that, because it happens when it's not running e.g. when using Chrome. So it can't be application-based, it must be drivers I think.

All I can think of is that there has been an update in Windows or elsewhere that is buggy, though I don't know how to roll back or where to roll back to. Rolling back seems to be a very crude way to pinpoint the issue.

The reason why I think it's the graphics is because, of the times it has frozen for a second or two, a few times out of those occasions, the screen has gone black, to come back with everything being redrawn and a message that "Display Driver Stopped Responding and Has Successfully Recovered" - speech bubble in bottom left of Desktop mode.

I may try a version of the following solutions:

http://www.computertipsfree.com/display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-successfully-recovered-nvlddmkm-nvidia-atikmdag-ati-windows-7-vista-xp/

Note that obviously I don't have nVidia on my Lenovo ThinkPad X201s, I have an integrated Intel HD Graphics chipset that I think is on the same die as the i7 CPU. So my steps will be different, if they are possible at all.

The above link works OK and has genuine advice and I am not connected to the site in anyway. The link came from here:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/14189-63-solved-display-driver-stopped-responding-successfully